# chrome.serial with Arduino Uno

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, arduino, arduino-uno

I'm storing information on Arduino Uno and then, when i plug the Arduino to the pc, I want google chrome to read incoming serial data(). I found Google's api http://developer.chrome.com/apps/serial, and think that this can help me. But actually i don't know how to use it :D

Here is my Arduino code which works fine:

```
//Importing libraries
#include <VirtualWire.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>

//Main temperature variable
float temp2;

//Measurements saving variable
int addr = 0;
int address = 0;
int tvalue =0;
int svalue;
//Function for saving data to Arduino's storage
int save_data_to_storage()
{
  EEPROM.write(addr, (temp2)*10);
  addr = addr + 1;
  if (addr == 12)
    addr = 0;
  delay(5000);
}

int save;

//Display variables
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

//Begin loops...

void setup()
{
  //Initialize serial port bitRate
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //Alarm pin
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT); 

  // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  // Print a message to the LCD For 7 seconds:
  lcd.print("BALGHI");
  delay(7000);
  lcd.clear();

  //Receiver set up
  vw_set_rx_pin(8);
  vw_rx_start();
  vw_setup(2000);
}
void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
      //Display USB Connection
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print("BALGHI");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print("USB Connection");

      // Send the measurements values to the PC
      svalue = EEPROM.read(address);
      //Serial.write(svalue);
      Serial.println(svalue, DEC);
      address = address + 1;
      if (address == 12){
         address = 0;
      //Delete all measurements data
         /*for (int d = 0; d < 12; d++)
           EEPROM.write(d, 0);*/
      }
      delay(500);
    }

    else{ 
      //Displaying temperature
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print("Body Temperature");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print(temp2, 1) + lcd.print(" C Degree");  

      // Get the message from the transmiter 
      uint8_t buflen = VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN;
      uint8_t buf[buflen];

      if(vw_get_message(buf, &buflen))
      {
         int i = 0; 
         //Convert the number to DEC
         float temp1 = (((buf[i]-48)*100+(buf[i+1]-48)*10+buf[i+2]-48));
         //Convert the number to C degrees
         temp2 = (temp1)/6.8; // k = 6.8
      }
      //store Numer
      //tvalue = (temp2, 1);

      //Alarm if Temperature is too high
      if(temp2 > 38.4) {
        digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(9, LOW);
        delay(1000); 
      }
      //Or keep calm
      else {
        digitalWrite(9, LOW);
      }

      //Write the measurement data to Arduino storage
      save = save_data_to_storage();
    }
}
```

Comment: http://renaun.com/blog/2013/05/using-the-chrome-serial-api-with-arduino/

Comment: I tried but it didn't work :|

Comment: Why. What errors you get

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on a plugin that does this. It is more extensive than what you are looking for, but you can possibly see how I have done it in my plugin.

FYI The plugin is the beginnings of an arduino editor in the browser. It couples with a server side application that compiles the code and returns it which is then flashed to the arduino. It can read and write to the serial port that the arduino is connected to.

You might just be interested in the chrome extension to see how I am getting serial data, however i have put the server side link as well

Chrome extension: https://github.com/DecodedCo/ArduinoInTheBrowser

Server side code: https://github.com/DecodedCo/ArduinoInTheBrowserServer

Answer (score 0):

I thinks this is what you need: http: //www. tigoe.com/pcomp/code/arduinowiring/1096/ (Remove spaces from the link)

It's an instruction on how to connect a serial device like arduino to broser using nod.js and websockets.
It uses express.js, socket.io and node-serialport libraries for nod.

Here’s the [index](https://github.com/tigoe/NodeExamples/blob/master/SerialToSocketIO/public/index.html) page. It loads the [client.js](https://github.com/tigoe/NodeExamples/blob/master/SerialToSocketIO/public/client.js) script, written with **P5.js**, that handles the socket communication. It opens a webSocket back to the server, and listens for events from the server. Whatever data it gets from the event, it prints to a DIV inside itself. Save these in a new subdirectory /nodeSerialServer/public.

Here’s the **server**: *https: //github.com/tigoe/NodeExamples/blob/master/SerialToSocketIO/server.js* (Remove spaces from the link)

It starts a web server and listens for HTTP requests for public/index.html, and serves it out when asked. It also listens for incoming webSocket requests, and opens them. When it does so, it start listening for serial events. If it gets a carriage return and newline in the serial port, it sends what it got out to the websocket. Save this in /nodeSerialServer.

To run this,  change directories to Save this in /nodeSerialServer:

cd /nodeSerialServer

then run the server.js script using node. To invoke this script, you need to give it the name of the serial port you want to open on the command line like so:

node server.js /dev/tty.usbportname

Put the name of your port into usbportname above.You’ll get a message that the script started. Now open a browser and open this address:
localhost:8080